# How to fix org.sonar.wsclient.connectors.connectionexception

Tags: java, netbeans, sonarqube, netbeans-8, sonar-runner

I installed kepler plugin in netbeans 8.0. And I tried to use sonar-runner using java application. I get a error "**Error executing sonar-runner**". 

Please help me with this. I really need to try this on java and java web applications. 

I tried sonarqube in eclipse same java project I used here. It is working perfectly..

 
[image: Erro]

[image: error1]

Comment: Exactly the same issue with NetBeans 8.2 (radar v. 3.1)